# ubuntu openjdk-7 the link "src.zip” is broken

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

[image]

I have installed OpenJDK 7 and it runs well on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I want to add Java sources to my Eclipse. When I go to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` there is a symlink called `src.zip` but it's broken. How do I fix this? Do I have to manually download sources and add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded sources from http://jdk7src.sourceforge.net/ and added them to eclilpse. It works fine now.

Comment: Note for future users, it is discouraged to install manually software on your machines, for different reasons (compatibility, security, auto updates). The answer by @Alex is preferred for these reasons.

Answer (score 41):

You should do:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-source
```

then the source code will be downloaded under: "/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-7".
The symlink:

```
src.zip -> ../openjdk-7/src.zip
```

should work now.

Comment: holy cow thank you I spent hours trying to figure out why I couldn't see JavaDoc sources / JavaDoc comments on Ubuntu 16.04 and OpenJDK 8 in Intellij.

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-doc openjdk-8-source` did it for me after reading your comment. Thanks a million!

Comment: Worked for java-8 too

Comment: Woked for java-11 too. Spent a lot of time trying to link the JavaDoc to Eclipse. Finally, this did work. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: tip: use [https://docs.oracle.com/](https://docs.oracle.com/) to find which file (if not sure where imported).
For example if interested in `getCurrencyInstance` then one finds it under [...docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()), therefore with [fuzzy finder](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) find the `NumberFormat` file in `/[unzip_directory]/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.java`, and there search for `getCurrencyInstance`.

Answer (score 8):

[The answer from Alex is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30961856/53897), as in how it *should* be.  However, for OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 18.10 it appears that src.zip has been moved to lib/src.zip so the symlink cannot be resolved.

In addition to the

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-source
```

command, run

```
echo "(cd /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/; ln -s lib/src.zip)" | sudo bash
```

to create an additional symbolic link.

Comment: `sudo apt install openjdk-11-source` downloads `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/lib/src.zip` so if previously `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/src.zip` pointed to `lib/src.zip` now still points there, but now there is actually that directory and .zip!

Comment: @XopiGarcía You are running 18.10?

Comment: I run 20.04, where your solutions YES works! I just wanted to explain how even if the soft link points to same path, only after running your command, that path (file) actually exists (but not before).

Comment: @XopiGarcía You should **only** run the snippet if you have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

installing openjdk8 again worked for me in ubuntu 16.04

step1: sudo apt install openjdk-8-source

step2 : attach the source.zip under(Window->preferences-java->Installed JREs->edit java-8-open-Jdk->expand rt.jar->click on Source attachment and attach the src.zip under /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64).